# Getting array of data using elemMatch is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to get particular object in array. My database structure is shown in below image
[image]

In this i am trying to get particular object like this

```
db.users.find({article:{$elemMatch:{articleid:"WMCA268937"}}})
```

but nothing is getting, someone please help.

Comment: typo? `articleid` vs `articleId`...

Comment: Yes, its my mistake. now working. here i am getting one article detail, If i want to get two article details. how to get two matched article records?